# How to get manufacturer name for each product

Tags: magento-1.9, php, adminhtml, manufacturer

I have to get some attributes for each product I've gotten most of them but I don't know how to get manufacturer name and the upc or ean barcode value in adminhtml.

I've tried with this code

```
         $name = 'Manufacturer';
         $attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter($name)->getFirstItem();
         $attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId(81);
         $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
         $attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
         var_dump($attribute);
```

But I can Just print (like in the image) $attribute level and then the $attributeOptions goes empty.

[image]

Comment: From where do you need to get manufacturer name?

Comment: @John I try to get collection (catalog/product) I can get sku, size, price, stock, description, name,qty... but I need to get also Brand/manufacturer and UPC/EAN barcode those I don't know how to can get them in magento 1.9

Comment: Are you using flat catalog?  Is the attribute set to be visible in product list?  Did you reindex?

Comment: @javaTodev, did you try using `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');`

Answer (score 4):

```
$productId='your_product_id';
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$manufaturer=$product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
```

Comment: I put it like this $produit = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(231);
   var_dump($produit->getAttributeText('manufacturer')); but result I receive is bool(false) only.

Comment: @javaTodev I think your attribute named manufaturer is yes/no attribute. If your manufacturer attribute is having different code then you have to put that code in the qoutes.

Comment: I've updated the post to see how I can get with a similar code.

Answer (score 2):

```
$name = 'manufacturer';

    $attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter($name)->getFirstItem();
    $attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
    $attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

    foreach ($attributeOptions as $_option){
        echo $_option['label'];

        $productcollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter($name, $_option['value']);

        foreach ($productcollection as $_product){
            echo $_product->getName();
        }
    }
```

Comment: as mentioned in the comment up I cannot get the manufacturer like this.

Comment: @javaTodev - now you can check my updated code above

Comment: Nothing . The field should be created or something like that? because I download a local version magento v1.9 but I didn't change nothing. In which table can I find the  Manufacturer/brand value in Database?

Comment: @javatodev  Did you assign the attribute to attribute set?

Comment: Is it the "attribute_set_id" ? because using this I doesn't work for me. I use a default version of magento1.9 That I have in localhost. So I don't know if you are sure about the manufacturer exist already for default products, and in which table I can find them?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php $attributes = $_product->getAttributes(); $Manufacturer = $attributes['manufacturer']->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); echo $Manufacturer; ?>
```